# Trouble clipping and ellipsoid surface mesh with a cone surface mesh (CGAL)

Tags: c++, cgal

**Problem:** I'm trying to use CGAL to generate a surface mesh which is the region on an ellipsoid bounded by the interior of a cone, but what I get in practice is the part of the ellipsoid surface which is bounded by the *exterior* of the cone.

**Method:** To do this, I've made use of two implicit functions, one for the ellipsoid (`ellipsoid_function`) and one for the cone (`cone_function`), and use the latter the clip the former (with `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::clip()`). The cone has its apex at the centroid of the ellipsoid (which is also the origin of the coordinate system) and its axis is aligned with the ellipsoid's semimajor axis.

To define the cone's included angle, which is 90 degrees, I compute the direction cosine of the position vector `p` with the cone's axis (z-axis), and subtract it from cos(90 degrees / 2) to give the return value of `cone_function`. Note that the sign of the return value is chosen to make the function negative in the interior region of the cone.

**Result:**

[image: Ellipsoid clipped by cone]

In fact, this result only occurs for some executions of the program. For others, no mesh is generated. Presumably the randomization is due to the stochastic nature of the mesh generation routine.

**Questions:** How is the region preserved by `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::clip()` determined if not by the return value of the clipping surface's implicit function? If it is being randomized by the mesh generation routine, how can I force it to be deterministic?

**Code:**

```
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/clip.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Complex_2_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/facets_in_complex_2_to_triangle_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/remesh.h>
#include <math.h>

// default triangulation for Surface_mesher
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3 Tr;
// c2t3
typedef CGAL::Complex_2_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C2t3;
typedef Tr::Geom_traits GT;
typedef GT::Sphere_3 Sphere_3;
typedef GT::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef GT::FT FT;
typedef FT (*Function)(Point_3);
typedef CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<GT, Function> Surface_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> Surface_mesh;

namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;
namespace params = CGAL::parameters;

FT ellipsoid_function (Point_3 p) {
  const FT z2 = p.z() * p.z();
  const FT rho2 = p.x() * p.x() + p.y() * p.y();
  return rho2 / 0.25 + z2 - 1.0; // Ellipsoid with semimajor axis parameter a == 1 and semiminor axis parameter b == 0.5
}

FT cone_function (Point_3 p) {
  FT r = sqrt(p.x()*p.x() + p.y()*p.y() + p.z()*p.z());
  FT cosTheta = p.z() / r; // Compute angle vector p makes with z-axis
  FT cosAlpha = cos(M_PI / 4); // M_PI / 4 == half of cone included angle (90 degrees)
  return cosAlpha - cosTheta;
}

// The following adapted from: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html#a5
int main() {
  Tr tr;            // 3D-Delaunay triangulation
  Tr tr2;
  C2t3 c2t3 (tr);   // 2D-complex in 3D-Delaunay triangulation
  C2t3 c2t32 (tr2);
  // defining the surface
  Surface_3 surface(ellipsoid_function,             // pointer to function
                    Sphere_3(CGAL::ORIGIN, 2.)); // bounding sphere
  // Note that "2." above is the *squared* radius of the bounding sphere!
  // defining meshing criteria
  Surface_3 surface2(cone_function,Sphere_3(CGAL::ORIGIN,2.));
  CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_criteria_3<Tr> criteria(30.,  // angular bound
                                                     0.1,  // radius bound
                                                     0.1); // distance bound
  // meshing surface
  CGAL::make_surface_mesh(c2t3, surface, criteria, CGAL::Non_manifold_tag());
  CGAL::make_surface_mesh(c2t32, surface2, criteria, CGAL::Non_manifold_tag());
  Surface_mesh sm;
  CGAL::facets_in_complex_2_to_triangle_mesh(c2t3, sm);
  Surface_mesh sm2;
  CGAL::facets_in_complex_2_to_triangle_mesh(c2t32, sm2);
  CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::clip(sm,sm2);
  PMP::isotropic_remeshing(faces(sm), 0.1, sm); 
  CGAL::draw(sm);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reverse the orientation if you have the bad side.